# AIX 'rm' command has no '-v' parameter for verbose output

Tags: rm, aix

The AIX `rm` command has no `-v` parameter for verbose output as stated by [IBM's documentation](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/aix/v7r1/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.aix.cmds%2Fdoc%2Faixcmds4%2Frm.htm).

Normally I would run (in linux)

```
rm -rfv <myfile>
```

to (**r**)ecursively and (**f**)orcably delete files and get the verbose output.

Since I can only run in AIX:

```
rm -rf <myfile>
```

How can I get the verbose output echoed into the terminal?

Answer (score 3):

AIX's `rm` `-e` option is analogous to GNU `rm`'s `-v`, from the `man` page :

```
-e
    Displays a message after each file is deleted.
```

Using it produces this result :

```
# rm -e test.txt
rm: Removing test.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

```
find myfile -depth -exec sh -c 'for f do
  rm -rf -- "$f" && printf "Removed ‘%s’\n" "$f"
  done' sh {} +
```

Or:

```
find myfile -depth -exec rm -rf -- {} \; \
                   -exec printf "Removed ‘%s’\n" {} \;
```

could be a start.

If you have access to GNU `find`, possibly as `gfind` or as `/opt/gnu/bin/find`:

```
gfind myfile -delete -printf 'Removed ‘%p’\n'
```

would be a lot more efficient as it would not run one (or more) command per file as the other ones.

But if you have `gfind`, you may also have `grm`...

Comment: +1. I didn't know the semicolon was optional when the in word is omitted.

Comment: @DimitreRadoulov, it's not only optional but forbidden by POSIX. And it won't work with it in the Bourne shell for instance. The syntax above is the most portable way to loop over the positional parameters. http://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/bourne_args/ for details

Answer (score 1):

Make `rm` into a function by adding this to your shell's initialization file (assuming Bourne-like syntax):

```
vrm() {
  for f do
    rm -- "$f" && printf 'Deleted %s\n' "$f"
  done
}
```

You can then call it as `vrm foo bar baz`.

Answer (score -2):

since @terdon missed the -r flag:

```
#!/bin/bash
vrrm(){
    for f in "$@"; do
        if [ -d "$f" ]; then
            gfind "$f" -type f -print0|tee >(gxargs -0 rm) |gxargs -0 echo -- removing file
            gfind "$f" -depth -type d -print0|tee >(gxargs -0 rmdir)|gxargs -0 echo -- removing directory
        else
            rm "$f" && echo Deleted $f
        fi
    done
}
```

Comment: No `-print0` or `-0` on AIX. Note that `[ -d` return true for symlinks to directories. `-type f` is regular files only, it's not the opposite of `-type d`. `echo` expands escape sequences so can't be used for arbitrary data. AIX `sh` doesn't support `>()`. There's a missing `--`.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas fixed.